# span does not accept fixed width when using with pdf library(p chart php)

Tags: html, css

I m facing an odd problem when using span tag for printing  a value in pdf file.
my span is not taking fixed width.

code is >

```
 <span style="background-color:#CC6600;color:#ffffff;width: 150px; display: inline-block;">d</span>
```

what should i do?

Comment: It should take.. I don't see any issues there

Comment: try this width: 150px !important;

Comment: Dear Alien code seems to be OK but problem exist that's why i posted question :(